# How can you update a file in Ruby on Rails / Paperclip / S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

My Ruby on Rails application uses S3 and Paperclip.  I have users upload a text file, which works fine.  I also want to allow them to edit the text file and resave it... this is where I'm confused.  Since they're not re-uploading any file, but rather EDITING the contents of the saved text file.  How can I do this?

Equivalently, how do you create / save a model with Paperclip, without uploading an actual file?

Here's something I tried...

```
Source.new(:user_id => 4,
           :name => "untitled.txt",
           :attachment_file_name => "untitled.txt",
           :attachment_content_type => "application/octet-stream",
           :attachment_contents => "This is a sample text file. Edit and resave to change this.")
      .save
```

PS - I'm saving the files on S3 instead of a database blog because they could potentially be large, and that seems unsuited for a database.

EDIT: I'm adding a bounty that I'll award to anyone who can show me how to do this without requiring the user to save a text file and reupload it.  I have a HTML textarea and want to offer an AJAXed "Save" button to resave a text file on S3.

Comment: Are you using the `aws-s3` gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are mixing two conceptually different approaches: DB store and file store. So from my point of view, you should go for either one of the 2 options:

**Option 1: Use a file storage (like Amazon S3)**

This seems to be answered thoroughly by Ben Simpson. If you want to allow the user to edit a file-backed resource, then you have to make sure to "manipulate the contents of the file on S3 outside of Paperclip."

**Option 2: Use db-storage**

It sounds to me like this is what you ultimately want to achieve. The file upload serves as the entry point for user-created content into your application. Since you are dealing with simple text files, I suggest saving the uploaded file's contents into your model, which you can then update just like any other model (including your ajax save).

For the initial values, i.e. "This is a sample text file. Edit and resave to change this.", you can either use the :default option in the migration file, or if you insist on a physical file to be present, use paperclip :default_url on the has_attached_file method along with a file that includes the template content.

Comment: You're right that I'm not sure the file storage is the best choice, but the reason I'm leaning towards it is that 1) you'll be able to upload other sorts of files, not just txt files, and 2) I might want to use Amazon Elastic MapReduce combined with those other files, so I thought it would be nice if they were all at Amazon.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Jeff, I do not have any experience with Amazon Elastic MapReduce, but understand that it is some sort of mass processing and analysis service. Given that, I think the answer largely depends on the requirements of your application. You should be able to do a fair amount of mass data analysis in your database as well - but then again, you are missing the benefits of the service. My advise: think about what is essential for your application and see if a simple db-backed solution works for you. If not, you still have the option to have the information in your db and mirror it to S3 asynchronously.

Comment: I think I will just use db-storage and mirror it, for now.  Thanks.  Do you have any suggestions on what to use for the Rails migration symbol, perhaps :binary?

Comment: Great to hear my answer helped. Regarding the type of your attribute in the migration file, the answer depends on what other file types you want to support. If it's just text (maybe including some RTF formatting which you handle on file upload), I would opt for :text -> should be much simpler to handle than :binary. :binary would be suitable if you wanted to store the whole file in db (but you only want its content in db, right?)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the aws-s3 gem, then you simply use that gem's API (not paperclip) to update the file:

`AWS::S3::S3Object.store 's3/path/to/untitled.txt', params[:textarea_contents_params_name], your_bucket_name`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with a file (multipart/form-data), you cannot display this data using HTML form fields. In order for a user to "edit" a text file would be to download the file, make changes and save, then upload the new file again.

In your responding controller's update action, you will need to update the attributes of the Source instance with the new params. This new file will result in the Paperclip gem overwriting the information for the old file, and replacing it with the new file. Assuming you are using the Rails form_for method, and the Paperclip helpers:

```
# app/controllers/source_controller.rb
class SourceController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @source = Source.find(params[:id])
    @source.update_attributes(params[:source]) # This will overwrite the old file information
  end
end
```

Paperclip will send Amazon S3 a request to remove the old file, and save the new file.

If you want to display the contents of this file to the user after they have finished uploading, you can do so via an HTML form element such as a text field, or text area. You will need to manipulate the contents of the file on S3 outside of Paperclip.

Comment: You're right that I'm displaying the contents in a textarea.  But are you sure you need to manipulate the contents outside of Paperclip, and then re-upload?  Surely there's a way to do this completely online in a browser!

Comment: What do you mean by "Surely there's a way to do this completely online in a browser!"? User submits the changed text, you wrap it in a file, send it to S3. Seems like it's all in the browser to me.

Comment: I guess what I mean is -- does an actual file have to exist somewhere, such as a temp file created by the server?  Or can you bypass that altogether as I'm attempting to do with my code?